# Trying to Join columns with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

So far after watching the tutorial videos on link, im fine accessing one data table and dealing with the results. On putting this into practice at the office I am faced with a lot of joins that I need to convert to LINQ...

**SELECT     Modules.TemplateFileName
FROM         Modules INNER JOIN
                      Grouping ON Modules.ID = Grouping.ModuleID
WHERE     (Grouping.ID = @id)**

(@id comes from querystring)

Could anyone please show me an example of the syntax needed to make it work?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at perforing JOINS in LINE to SQL, here is an example:

```
AdventureWorksDataContext aw = new AdventureWorksDataContext();

    aw.Log = Console.Out;

    var entities = from e in aw.Employees
                   join ea in aw.EmployeeAddresses on e.EmployeeID equals ea.EmployeeID
                   join a in aw.Addresses on ea.AddressID equals a.AddressID
                   join c in aw.Contacts on e.ContactID equals c.ContactID

                   where e.EmployeeID == employeeID

                   select new
                   {
                       Title = e.Title,
                       FirstName = c.FirstName,
                       LastName = c.LastName,
                       City = a.City,
                       AddressID = ea.AddressID
                   };
```

You can do a google serach and find a lot of example on it.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have an actual question, but just want us to do your work for you, doesn't it?

Comment: if you have nothing helpful to add. Rather add nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started...

```
var fileName = from mod in db.Modules
join groupings in db.Grouping on mod.ID equals groupings.ModuleID
where groupings.ModuleID == idFromQueryString
select new { mod.TemplateFileName }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var example = from m in dataContext.Modules
              join g in dataContext.Grouping on m.ID equals g.ModuleID
              where g.ID == groupID
              select new { m.TemplateFileName };
```